# getResponseBody resultsin hGetBuf: resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: haskell

calling a slow (> secs) on the web with a HTTP call in haskell (package HTTP) works, but occasionally i experience an error `"<socket: 3>: hGetBuf: resource vanished (Connection reset by peer)`. the same server served a dozen requests before and is available afterwards. what do is wrong?

the code - with error catching to pinpoit the source of the problem - is

```
    callHTTP3 :: Http.Request B.ByteString -> ErrIO Text
-- | executes the HTTP call (e.g. simpleHTTP) and deals with first level of failure
callHTTP3 req = do
        putIOwords ["callHTTP3:"]
        body1 <- callIO $  do
                    -- body <- Http.httpLBS req  -- would be from conduit
                    response <- Http.simpleHTTP req
                    body <-  Http.getResponseBody response
                    return body
                `catchError` \(e) -> do
                    putIOwords ["callHTTP3 error in simpleHTTP or getResponseBody", showT e]
                    fail . unwords $  [ "callHTTP3 httperror 4", show e]
                    -- return . Left , unlines' $  [ "callHTTP3 httperror 4 throw ", show e]
        let body2 = checkUTF8 $ body1
        putIOwords ["callHTTP3:  show checked body", showT body2]
        return  body2
    `catchError` (\e -> do
            putIOwords ["callHTTP3 error caught", showT e] -- " showT msg])
            return ""
            )
```

Comment: this reminds me of an issue I filed in the turtle library - https://github.com/Gabriel439/Haskell-Turtle-Library/issues/102 - the solution was to replace `""` with `Text.empty` - I have not studied your problem thouroughly so I just post this as a comment.

Comment: interesting comment (and the linked issue) . I will try it, but do not expect too much, given that the empty string is here only in the error return.